# Cell-complex representating X and n-skeletons

Tags: general-topology

Consider the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with cyclically identified edges. That is $(x,0)\sim(1,x)\sim(1-x,1)\sim(0,1-x)$. Draw a cell complex representating X and determine the n-skeleton of X for $n=1,2,3$.

My attempt: We have a square so we have 4 0-cells (corners), 4 1-cells and one 2-cell. But I cant say that I understand  the above notation for the corners of how to continue.

Comment: I only see one vertex and one edge.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but its a square? The number of 0-cells,1-cells and 2-cells was a tip from my teacher.

Comment: A square, with all its edges identified, and all its vertices identified.

Comment: Sadly I still dont get it @LordSharktheUnknown